# VBA Copy merged area

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filer a set of data in another workbook and then copy the full range of the filtered data and paste it into ppt. I have managed to get the filter working but i am struggling to copy the merged data.

I am getting the error

> Run-time eror '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

on the line `rng.MergeArea.Copy`

```
Function FilterCopyPasteActionLog(Sld As Integer, rng As Range, LeftPos As Integer, TopPos As Integer, WidthPos As Integer, HeightPos As Integer, DataTyp As Integer, wB As String, sH As String) As Object
        If PPT Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        If PPT_pres Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        Dim mySlide As Object
        Dim myShape As Object

        Workbooks(wB).Worksheets(sH).Activate

        'Find the LastRow
        Dim LastLine As Long
        LastLine = Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row

        'Add filter
        Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Open"

        'Copy the filtered data.
        Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        rng.MergeArea.Copy 'ERROR HERE

        Set mySlide = PPT_pres.Slides(Sld)

        PasteRngIntoSlide mySlide, DataTyp

        PositionChart LeftPos, TopPos, WidthPos, HeightPos

        'Clear Clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Any help, or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: On what row of your code do you get the error?

Comment: rng.MergeArea.Copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentRegion` and `MergeArea` are two different properties, that cannot go together. You are practically writing this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.MergeArea.Copy    
End Sub
```

which always returns `1004` error. To see the `MergedArea` in `CurrentRegion`, a loop around the `CurrentRegion` is doable:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        If Not myCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            myCell.Copy
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation, I am trying to copy the full range of filtered data, which will vary in number of rows, not columns. I tried just using rng.copy but this fell over because it was merged.

Comment: @TisButaScratch - see the edit, it distinguishes merged from non-merged.